# How do I make a trigger that would check for eligibility in oracle?

Tags: database, plsql, oracle11g, triggers

```sql
create table Student
(studID char(4) PRIMARY KEY,
studName varchar2(20) NOT NULL,
studPhone varchar2(12) NOT NULL,
studElig char(1) NOT NULL);

create table Sports
(sportsID char(4) PRIMARY KEY,
sportsName varchar2(20) NOT NULL,
beginDate date NOT NULL,
sportsNotes varchar2(50) NULL,
coachID char(4));

create table Coach
(coachID char(4) PRIMARY KEY,
coachName varchar2(20) NOT NULL,
coachOffice varchar2(7) NOT NULL,
coachOphone varchar2(12) NOT NULL,
coachCphone varchar2(12) NOT NULL);

create table Sports_Enrolment
(studID char(4) NOT NULL,
sportsID char(4) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(studID,sportsID),
FOREIGN KEY(studID) REFERENCES Student(studID),
FOREIGN KEY(sportsID) REFERENCES Sports(sportsID));

ALTER TABLE Sports
ADD CONSTRAINT coach_fk
FOREIGN KEY (coachID)
REFERENCES Coach(coachID)
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

**So what I am trying to do is every time a student is added to the Sports Enrolment table, it checks studElig (1 or 0) before adding it and prints messages if it is successful or not.**

Comment: You will get more out of school if you work on these problems yourself for a while before asking others to write your code for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SE_INSERT
BEFORE INSERT ON Student_Enrollment
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
      stdE NUMBER(10):=0;
BEGIN
      SELECT studElig INTO stdE FROM Student WHERE studId=:NEW.studId;
    
      IF stdE=1 THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('It is eligible');
      ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('It is not eligible');
      END IF;
END;
```

Comment: I hope it works!

Comment: Hi. The trigger has no problem being created but does not output the messages you have set here. It just says, "1 row created". Also, I edited Student_Enrollment from your code to Sports_Enrolment. Why is this happening?

Comment: I think you working on SQL command LINE prompt if you want to it will show the PL SQL  output then you should to execute the SETSERVEROUTPUT ON command. You can also write this in TRIGGER code.